# How to tell grep to ignore folders in Spacemacs project keyword/symbol search?

Tags: emacs, grep, spacemacs, emacs-helm

In spacemacs you can `spc s p` to find keywords within your project, in my case Spacemacs uses grep as it is the first search tool it finds according to its `dotspacemacs-search-tools` configuration.

My problem is that in projects where I have a folder with compiled javascript, Helm/Grep looks for said keyword within those folders, making Spacemacs either freeze or sometimes crash, how can I tell Helm (within the context of Spacemacs) to ignore such folders?

Here is an example of how it looks like:
[image]

I've tried looking for some clues in the help section of `(C-c ?)` but haven't found anything yet.

Any help is appreciated :)

**Edit/Update:** Bahman's answer is in fact correct. Note however that in my case I had to also include a directory inside "projectile-globally-ignored-directories" configuration in order to work:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, Emacs search (grep/ag/...) commands have an *ignored-directories* customization option exposed as a list.

Based on the screenshot, I think you're using *helm-grep*.

You can simply evaluate the following or add it to your Emacs config:

```
(add-to-list 'helm-grep-ignored-directories "node_modules")
```

You can also `M-x customize` and then search for "helm-grep" to view/edit any of its options including ignored directories.

Comment: How about "hidden" directories? your answer works with the node_modules directory for example but in my case helm-grep is still looking into a directory with a dot preceding its name that I have already included in the ignored-directories list.

Comment: Strange. Even if you append a `/` to the directory? Is this a git repo? Are you using projectile?

Comment: Yes! sorry, I was updating the question with that detail, I had to also include the directory (in my case .shadow-cljs) inside projectile-globally-ignored-directories list config :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **AG Search** instead

[image]

Because **AG Search** is more integrated and polish, and the other methods weren't improved or fixed to work well with this Ignore options.

When I tested the other methods (grep/ag/...) they didn't perform as expected. Like for example they didn't ignore folders in the search and they purely search for everything in any folder. They will need more development to work as expected.